# What should I know as a new D&D player, playing Velynne Harpell on Rime of the Frost Maiden?

Tags: dnd-5e, rime-of-the-frostmaiden

This is my first game of D&D or any other tabletop role-playing game. I get the general idea of the mechanics from games such as Neverwinter Nights so I can understand dice rolling, spells, leveling, etc.

I have been asked to join a game of D&D by the DM. They are currently playing *[Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Icewind_Dale:_Rime_of_the_Frostmaiden)* an my role will be embodying *[Vellynne Harpell](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Vellynne_Harpell)*. To my knowledge from what the DM told me, everything seems to match with what [I could find here about her](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Vellynne_Harpell).

So far the DM has given me a general idea of the world and the story, a general idea of who my character is and walked my through building the character sheet.

I know he will help me get up to speed, but I would like to be as prepared as I can for the first day so I can be a good addition to the party and bring realism to my character.

What should I know about the world as Vellynne Harpell?

What additional information should I ask for?

Is there anything I should definitely know as a new D&D player?

Comment: Welcome to the stack Lando, take the [tour] when you have a moment. . As written, I’m not sure this question is a good fit. It looks like a call mostly for general advice, which we don’t really do here. Is there something specific about Vellynne you are trying to figure out? I’ve voted to close as “opinion based” for now. You might have better luck at a traditional discussion forum, see [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) for our curated list.

Comment: Hello Lando, as Thomas said, this probably isn't the best place for advice on roleplaying specific characters. I'd recommend you check out the Rime of the Frostmaiden subreddit instead. (Check with your DM first though since it's easy to stumble onto spoilers there.)

Comment: Thank you both, I'll check the list and the subreddit. I'm trying to walk the thin line between being useful and prepared for the adventure and not stumbling onto spoilers at the same time :).

I'm guessing I will have better suited questions as I progress in the game.